# Failed to get gamma size for single monitor default output

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, display-resolution, nvidia-geforce

i am on ubuntu 22.04 for almost 3 months. I'm a beginner in linux. So far, no problems have been found. Until in the end I kept my computer in my storage room for 3 weeks, and then I started it again. This is where the problem starts, where the desktop screen becomes large and there is only 640x480 resolution.[you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVzIg.jpg)

i type xrandr in cli and output like this:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum                
640 x 480
default connected primary 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
640x480       73.00*
```

I've tried to find various ways that I found on ubuntu ask. started from changing to gdm3, etc., but this still doesn't work.

i am using nvidia geforce gt 730 and found no problems before i kept my computer in storage for 2 weeks and when i restarted it i had this kind of problem.

does anyone know how to solve it. I'm still a beginner. I will be very grateful to anyone who can help me.